# Does SerNet compile Samba 4 with CUPS support? (How to tell in general?)

Tags: centos, compiling, samba, cups, options

I have SerNet Samba 4.0.9 installed on CentOS 6.4.  How can I tell if it was compiled with CUPS support?

Comment: If you're using the RPM's SerNet is putting out you should be able to pull the spec file then look to see if `--enable-cups` is in the configure. Currently researching a more generic way post-install, though.

Comment: Well I'm still not sure so I may have to wait to see if someone else answers. In Samba3x smbd would link against libcups so you could do a `ldd` on it to see if it was built with support. It looks like printing is now more opaque to the rest of Samba4 so it's not as obvious if there's cups support without looking at the spec file.

Comment: @JoelDavis thanks for the lead, but even with my SerNet login, I don't see anywhere that they have a spec file.  Maybe I just have to ask them.

Comment: Well you would use `rpm2cpio` to extract the files from the rpm to a directory. In the base directory there will be a file named `<packageName>.spec` and you can find the configure options in that. But it looks like you found the answer anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs, which say they're valid for Samba 3 and 4](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_as_a_print_server#Uploading_printer_drivers_for_Point.27n.27Print_driver_installation), say:

"...make sure, that your smbd is compiled with CUPS support:"

```
# smbd -b | grep CUPS
   HAVE_CUPS_CUPS_H
   HAVE_CUPS_LANGUAGE_H
   HAVE_CUPS
   HAVE_LIBCUPS
```